# Как работает деструктуризация параметра в этом примере?

Tags: javascript

В mdn в разделе про стрелочные функции есть такие примеры:

```js
var elements = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium','Beryllium'];

elements.map(({ "length": lengthFooBArX }) => lengthFooBArX); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

или

elements.map(({ length }) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Не могу понять, как из текущего элемента массива извлекается *length* через деструкруризацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот один из примеров для понимания. Можете [почитать](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta)

```js
const obj = {
  length: 1
};

const {length} = obj;
console.log(length);
```

В вашем примере используется деструктуризация объекта, когда вы используете функцию, вот пример с функцией:

```js
const obj = {
  length: 1
};

function destructuringStart({length}) {
  console.log(length);
}

destructuringStart(obj);
```

Comment: Точно, я забыл, что строка это объект со свойством length.